# Why does knowing the $n$th derivative of a function at a point allow you to know the functions value everywhere else?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I apologise if this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find anything answering my specific question.

My question is why does knowing the $n$ derivative at a *point* allow you to approximate (or know exactly, for an infinite Taylor series for functions like $\sin(x)$) a function at places (far) away from that point.

Specifically if you consider the Sine functions Taylor Series:
$$ \sin(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{{2n+1}!} $$
We could derive this series by considering the $n$th derivative of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ which turns out to only be $4$ different values (after the first four it repeats). It seems strange to me that knowing infinitely well what the derivative of the Sine function is at $x=0$ allows one to know the value for the function at $x=1000$ (or any number).

It seems that encoded in the derivative(s) of a function (at a point) must be information that entirely defines that function (for functions like the Sine function). Though there's most likely a flaw in my thinking somewhere, I've only started looking into series. Is there any intuitive way of understanding why knowing infinitely well a function at a point can define a function anywhere?

Comment: It sounds as though you are asking for proof of why Taylor's theorem holds.  The wiki article has some information on that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Proofs

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, I've had a quick look at the article. It explains "similarly, we get still better approximations to f if we use polynomials of higher degree, since then we can match even more derivatives with f at the selected base point." My question is why (intuitively, it seems makes sense in terms of proofs) is this the case? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions with this property are "nice" in a strong sense; specifically they are called *real analytic*. Generally "analytic" means "representable as a power series", although usually "analytic" without specification is used to describe a *complex analytic* function.

This turns out to be a strictly stronger property than merely having infinitely many derivatives, because there are functions which are smooth but grow slower than any polynomial near a specified point. One such function is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}, & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

This function is *not* identically zero, clearly. Perhaps surprisingly, it *is* infinitely differentiable, even at zero. Yet one can prove that its Taylor polynomials at zero are all identically zero. So this function is not real analytic.

This is an especially nasty example because the Taylor series converges for any $x$ that you substitute, yet it only converges to the function $f$ at $0$ itself, never anywhere else. There are functions "in between" where the Taylor series does agree on a neighborhood but not globally. For instance:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

is equal to its Taylor series at $0$ on the interval $(-1,1)$. Yet beyond this interval the series fails to converge at all, even though $f$ is defined and smooth over the whole line. These functions are called real analytic on the domain where the series converges.

Properly studying this phenomenon requires complex analysis, at least in my opinion. For instance, for the previous function, one can identify the fact that the Taylor series converges only on $(-1,1)$ with the fact that the Taylor series of the corresponding *complex* function converges only on the disk of radius $1$ centered at zero. It could never converge on any larger disk because it blows up at $z=i$.

Perhaps surprisingly, the properties of Taylor *polynomials* (not series) can be understood using only real-variable methods. Taylor's theorem (with its various error estimates) is all there is to say on the subject.

Comment: Mild disagreement with your opening paragraph: "analytic" is used to mean "representable by a power series" in any context.  It so happens that any "real analytic" function also has a "complex analytic" extension; so there is no ambiguity in simply referring to the function (or the "germ" thereof) as analytic.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right. I edited accordingly. I do think it is helpful to know that just "analytic" usually means "complex analytic", even though this is somewhat sloppy use of terminology.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the answer! I briefly read Spivak's Calculus that seemed to briefly touch on some of the ideas you mentioned; I'll have a more thorough look. The thing that I don't seem to understand is that why does knowing about how a function behaves around a point (i.e. its derivatives) allow one to make the step to then define a polynomial - using this information - that defines the functions behaviour everywhere else. Thanks

Comment: @Jay It only works for the right function. One way of looking at it is that there is one function which has the specified derivatives *and* has a power series expansion. There may be other functions which have the *same* specified derivatives but don't actually have a power series expansion, or perhaps only have a power series expansion on part of their domain.

Comment: @Ian So for a function with specific derivatives at a point, say $0$, then it could so happen that the power series defined by those specified derivatives could equal the function. But it's also the case that many other functions  share those same specific derivatives at $0$ (which would therefore give the same expansion) but aren't the same as the power series expansion. Would I be correct in viewing a Taylor series as being potentially defined by many functions (i.e. with the same derivatives at a point) but there's only one function that equals the Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Jay That's correct. (Technically, we should be saying "convergent Taylor series" instead of just "Taylor series" in these statements, but I think you get the idea.) This fact is actually a little bit vacuous, because the function which agrees with the Taylor expansion *is* the Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Ian Awesome, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some intuition (not a rigorous argument).

\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x f'(s) \, ds \\
\tag{$\clubsuit$} &\approx f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \underbrace{f'(x_0)}_{\text{zeroth-order approximation to } f'(s)} \, ds \\
&= f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0).
\end{align}

But we can get a better approximation by using a better approximation for $f'(s)$ in step $(\clubsuit)$:

\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x f'(s) \, ds \\
\tag{$\spadesuit$}& \approx f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \underbrace{f'(x_0) + f''(x_0)(s - x_0)}_{\text{first-order approximation to } f'(s)} \, ds \\
&= f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac12 f''(x_0)(x - x_0)^2.
\end{align}
This approximation seems likely to be superior to the first-order approximation derived above.

By using higher-order approximations to $f'(s)$ in step ($\spadesuit$), such as
\begin{equation}
f'(s) \approx f'(x_0) + f''(x_0)(s - x_0) + \frac12 f'''(x_0) (s - x_0)^2,
\end{equation}
we get higher-order Taylor approximations to $f(x)$, and it seems like these approximations should be increasingly accurate.  So we can hope that the Taylor series for $f(x)$ will be exact.

(Of course, this doesn't always happen, but we at least have a reason for hoping it will happen.)

Comment: I'm not sure how much this helps. We should only *really* expect the Taylor polynomials to become better approximations on a neighborhood of the point of expansion, and that neighborhood might very well start to get smaller and smaller as we use higher degree polynomials.

Comment: @Ian Well, this is certainly only an intuitive argument.  It gives us a reason to hope for something.  It won't always work out as nicely as we hope.